# How to use Upgrader Plugin on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use upgrader plugin for myapps, because i need to use the auto update on ios too. But the problem is i don't know how to use it. And my apps looks like this. [image]

and here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile7/class/login.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

class CheckUpdate extends StatefulWidget {
static const String id = 'login_screen';
@override
_CheckUpdateState createState() => _CheckUpdateState();
}

 class _CheckUpdateState extends State<CheckUpdate> {
  final Login login = Login();
 bool isLoading = true;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SafeArea(
   child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Upgrade Example'),
      ),
      body: _checkPlatform()),
  );
 }
 }

  Widget _checkPlatform() {
  Widget upgraderAlert;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    upgraderAlert = UpgradeAlert(
     dialogStyle: UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino,
     child: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
   );
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   upgraderAlert = UpgradeAlert(
     dialogStyle: UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino,
     child: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
    );
   }

   return upgraderAlert;
   }
```

i read the documentation and it's says that i just need to wrap it up in that UpgraderAlert but it's didn't do anything  help me solve this

here is upgrader plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader

Comment: Did you read the [`README.md`](https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader/blob/master/README.md) document, and did you ask questions on the [issue page](https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader/issues)?

Comment: i read the readme, but still waiting an answer from my question on issue page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use upgrader on Android, you must setup an Appcast file and provide the configuration. Here is an example Appcast file you need to place on a server somewhere, such as GitHub. The Appcast file contains the details about the latest version of the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle">
    <channel>
        <title>Debt Now App - Appcast</title>
        <item>
            <title>Version 1.15.0</title>
            <description>desc</description>
            <pubDate>Sun, 30 Dec 2018 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moonwink.treasury" sparkle:version="1.15.0" sparkle:os="android" />
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is a build method that will use the Appcast file on Android, and provide the AppcastConfiguration. This configuration will not apply to iOS, but iOS will continue to work.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appcastURL =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larryaasen/upgrader/master/test/testappcast.xml';
    final cfg = AppcastConfiguration(url: appcastURL, supportedOS: ['android']);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Upgrader Example',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Upgrader Example'),
          ),
          body: UpgradeAlert(
            appcastConfig: cfg,
            child: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Don't we need to add any code for iOS, not even in plist file as well?

Comment: @himCream As long as you have the normal iOS properties set inside your Info.plist file for Bundle Name, Bundle Identifier, Bundle Version, Bundle Version String, and Bundle Display Name, that is all you need.

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much for reply @Laryy Aasen

Comment: Is there any way to check the upgrader  without adding to app store ?

Comment: @minyu I'd like to answer your question about upgrader but I don't understand it. Can you ask a new question in Stack Overflow, instead of adding a comment?

Comment: ` UpgradeAlert(
              upgrader: Upgrader(appcastConfig: cfg),
              child: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
            )`     appcastConfig: cfg  writes inside Upgrader